# function in c++ that takes the month number and prints the number of days for the month

Tags: c++, if-statement, days

the code worked before I added in the part where if the user enters in a number higher then 12 I want it to say "not a number for a month." im trying to get if and else to work but it just always stops the program im also new to programming sorry for bad format. Any help is good. thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int month = 0;
int days;

cout << "Month: ";
cin >> month;

if (month != 1 || month != 2 || month != 3 || month != 4 || month != 5 || 
    month != 6 || month != 7 || month != 8 || month != 9 || month != 10 || 
    month != 11 || month != 12 ) {

cout<<"not a number for a month";

return 0;

}


if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
    days = 30;

else 

days = 31;

cout << days;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want `&&`. Or you could `if (month < 1 || month > 12) {...`

Comment: So if you enter `2` for `month`, `month != 1` will be `true` and you will go into the `if`. If you fix it as Bathsheba indicated it will be slightly better: it will return 31 for February but at least it'll work for all other months :-)

Comment: Learn the basic difference between || and && operator. Your basics are not clear.

Comment: February, 31? That's my birthday and I'm glad someone finally wrote a program that recognize that date!

Comment: My dear lady wife proposed to me on February 29th: Make sure you include that one too.

Answer (score 5):

Replace that utterly evil `if` conditional with

```
if (month < 1 || month > 12){
```

Besides being ghastly, you are using `||` in error: your conditional is always `true`. You needed `&&`.

Then fix the special case for `month == 2`. At that point you'll need to know the year.

As a rule of thumb: if you find yourself writing very tedious code, then there is probably a simpler way of expressing your intent.

Comment: Also use Switch statements ;)

Comment: And for date and time related business, use library functions. Those are _nasty_.

Comment: @YSC: Absolutely. I use the date and time libraries from Boost, which are excellent.